# Configure subdomains with nginx

Tags: nginx, server, digital-ocean

I need to preface this by saying I have never set up a server before.  That said I am trying to set up a nginx server on digital ocean.  I have the main site up and running but I am trying to set up a sub domain.  I don't really know what I am doing but I have the ssl certs working But I can't seem to get the sub domain to show.  I get a browser error `Page isn't working too many redirects in the browser`.  I ran the command to test ngninx syntax and it passed.  I thought all I had to do was add a server block with the root pointing to the folder but I guess I may be wrong or I did something wrong on the way.  The main site is a node app and is running fine but right now I am just trying to serve up a static html file in the sub domain.  I restarted nginx and then I even tried rebooting but no luck.  Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file:

```
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    if ($host = dev.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80  ;
    server_name example.com, dev.example.com;
    return 404;

}

server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


}

server {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    server_name dev.example.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /home/username/apps/dev;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have `env-one.example.com` in two `server_name` directives, so I do not understand why the configuration file does not throw warnings. The penultimate `server` block is redirecting to itself. I am not sure what the intent is here.

Comment: @RichardSmith I edited the question with a revised sites-enabled file.  Having multiple server_name directives doesn't really matter one would just be ignored.  The redundant blocks were added by certbot and I cleaned it up a little.  But I still get the same behavior and the main site where I am running a node app works fine.

Comment: As @Richard says, your last server block redirects to itself.  Try removing the first line `return 301...`

Comment: @chuex Thanks I didn't even see that.  I used certbot to add the sub domain and it added the code blocks and I just modified them I didn't even pay attention to that first line.  I feel like an idiot.  Its working now thanks.